# Hide Completed and other finished pods by default

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my professional environment it is common for "completed" pods to outnumber active ones and they often clutter the output of `kubectl get pods` like so:

```
$ kubectl get pods
finished-pod-38163    0/1 Completed    2m
errored-pod-83023     0/1 Error        2m
running-pod-20899     1/1 Running      2m
```

I can filter them out using `--show-all=false`:

```
$ kubectl get pods --show-all=false
running-pod-20899     1/1 Running      2m
```

However I would prefer not to have to type out `--show-all=false` every time I want to see my running pods. Is it possible to configure `kubectl` to *disable* `--show-all` *by default* rather than having it enabled by default?

From `kubectl get pods --help`:

```
-a, --show-all=true: When printing, show all resources (default show all pods
                     including terminated one.)
```

I know I could create some shell alias `kgetpo`, but this would remove support for tab-completion so I'd prefer native solutions if they exist.

Comment: This is an issue report/feature request for https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/new. As you see, the default is `--show-all=true`. :) As a sidenote, I'm maintainer of https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectl-aliases/, and as far as I can tell on zsh, completion still works with aliases.

Comment: Sounds like the answer is, "You can't do this." At least, given vanilla `kubectl`. I love your linked `kubectl-aliases` project though, it looks very interesting and I'll check it out. I do notice that it doesn't seem to have an alias for `--show-all=false` though.

Comment: Looks like a good enhancement, submitted this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/537

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase==Running
```